# How to update a table after saving data from the form

Tags: php, yii, boolean

Am trying to update a a table after saving data from the form.
When I set save(false) it works but fails when I use save().

```
case 1:
          parentpage->status=2;
          parentpage->save(false);
          break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because when you call `model->save(false)` it does not trigger validations. What you have to do is fix the validations in the model, compared to the data you have. If you update your question with what data you are trying to put in and what the validations are, I will tell you what is wrong with the query.

Comment: This is the model